# Cross thread issue in Qt4.8

Tags: qt, qt4

I have this code:

class CMyWindow:

```
class CMyWindow: public QMainWindow
{ // Q_OBJECT .... here  
private:
    CMyServer *server;
public:
    CMyWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        // Setup GUI here
        server = new CMyServer(this);
        server->startServer();
    }
    void thisChangeLabelCaption(QString str) {
        ui.lblStatus.setText(str);
    }
}
```

And class CMyServer:

```
class CMyServer: public QTcpServer
{       
protected:
    void incomingConnection(int sockDesc) {
        /* Why below line can't be done :-| */
        ((CMyWindow *) parent())->thisChangeLabelCaption("New connection");
    }
}
```

But the line in incomingConnection() rountine seem not executed.

Please tell me solution for this problem.

**Update:**
As @vtmarvin said, i tried this way:

```
class CMyWindow: public QMainWindow
{
private:
    CMyServer *server;
protected slots:
    void editLabel(QString str) {
        thisChangeLabelCaption(str);
    }

public:
    CMyWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent) {
        server = new CMyServer(this);
        server->startServer();
    }

    void thisChangeLabelCaption(QString str) {
        ui.lblStatus.setText(str);
    }
}

class CMyServer: public QTcpServer
{
Q_SIGNAL:
    void setText(QString str);

protected:
    void incomingConnection(int sockDesc) {
        /* Why below line can't be done :-| */
        emit setText("New connection");
    }

public:
    CMyServer(QObject *parent): QTcpServer(parent)
    {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(setText(QString)), parent, SLOT(editLabel(QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    }
}
```

But no better result :-(

Comment: And where are you calling incomingConnection()?

Comment: incomingConnection() overrided from QTcpServer class, it is called when new connection available

Comment: documentation says: "Call listen() to have the server listen for incoming connections.". Where do you call that?

Comment: It's called in startServer() but i have stripped since stackoverflow prohibite posting long source code. Sorry for that

Comment: Are you sure that its reaching incomingConnection?

Comment: @spyke: Yes i do, if i use QMessageBox to show message in incomingConnection() then it run succnessfully

Answer (score 1):

[You cannot change UI from other threads than the main one](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/threads-qobject.html) - the one that owns QMainWindow. I suppose your CMyServer::incomingConnection is invoked by the QTcpServer thread. You must do a signal-slot with Qt::QueuedConnection type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have tried but no result. I have edited my question :)

Comment: Can you prove that the execution still arrives all the way to `thisChangeLabelCaption` ?

Comment: If i replace the line `((CMyWindow *) parent())->thisChangeLabelCaption("New connection");` with `QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "I got there");` then it run succnessfully and show me the messagebox, but why above do not affect to label?

Comment: Oh man, i am asking whether `thisChangeLabelCaption` is executed after you added signal-slot, not your original `incomingConnection` before signal-slot. Is the signal emitted? Is it received? Print something. Add your message box in CMyWindow.

Comment: I hanen't tested this, but it seem the label caption not change :-(